# using query_posts to query wordpress WPML

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wpml

I have this code in a page template to reach only one category

```
<?php query_posts ( array( 'category__and' => array(7), ) ); ?>
```

the problem in that in WPML when i change language no posts are in page template. Does WPML change posts category ID when translating? 
how can i get the correspondent post in the correct language?

Comment: got the solution